# c# : пример выполнения GET запроса

Tags: c#, post, rest, get

День добрый, никак не могу разобраться с корректным выполнением GET запроса.
Имеется API, из которого я без проблем получаю данные с помощью curl :

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: LocalTocken" -H "X-User-Id: LocalID" https://api.local/tables?tableName=myTable
```

Запрос возвращает корректные данные. Пытаюсь выполнить простейший запрос на C#:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://api.local/tables?tableName=myTable"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Auth-Token", "LocalTocken");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-User-Id", "LocalID");    
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response);

    }
}
```

В результате получаю абракадабру :

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  x-xss-protection: 1
  x-instance-id: 2sdf5dsdfesdf6fp2DS
  pragma: no-cache
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Date: Wed, 06 May 2020 09:45:58 GMT
  Server: nginx/1.17.9
  Content-Language: ru
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

Где можно увидеть простейший пример синхронного GET и POST запроса?

Comment: Вы получили ответ с его статусом, заголовками и прочим, но не контент. Сделайте еще `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. Пару замечаний. 1. Заголовки добавляйте прям клиенту при помощи простого `.Add()`. 2. Вам не нужен `HttpRequestMessage`, используйте просто `client.GetAsync('url")`. 3. Если используете `.Result`, то `await` в начале не нужен. Примерно [такой](https://pastebin.com/aCN7V4fW) результат у вас должен быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь ошибка:

```csharp
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

Именно поэтому я не люблю ключевое слово `var`, сильно мешает ловить подобное.

Ответ прочитать можно вот так.

```csharp
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Еще у вас скорее всего опечатка `"LocalTocken"`, наверное должно быть `"LocalToken"`.

**Дополнительно**

Не создавайте `HttpClient` для каждого запроса, его экземпляры просто забьют вам все сокеты и вы просто потеряете связь. Об этом написано в примере кода в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8).

> ```csharp
> // HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.
> ```

Создайте один глобальный `HttpClient` и используйте его где нужно. Диспозить его не требуется, несмотря на то что он `IDisposable`, но если хочется, то можно вызвать `Dispose()` при завершении работы приложения, он по сути только отменяет активные HTTP запросы, выполняет `CancelPendingRequests()`.

```csharp
private HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
```